# How to generate Digital Surface Model (DSM) from aerial image?

Tags: imagine-photogrammetry

Can I use Erdas LPS 2011 for automated DSM generation with low resolution (5m to 15m) by one aerial image?

I don't have a stereo pair images for the city.

Comment: Describe DSM for the GIS-SE Users please

Comment: I thought it would be common knowledge to GIS users ( along with DEM, DTM ).

Comment: @R.K. Sure: everybody knows it means Demand Side Management. And Distributed Shared Memory, Domain Specific Modeling, Digital Surface Model, Design Structure Matrix, and a few dozen other things. More to the point is what "automated DSM generation" might mean, because obviously it's impossible to infer elevations from a single aerial image, even though that's what "Digital Surface Model generation" would *seem* to mean. That's why we always ask people to spell out their acronyms.

Comment: I do not believe that single image elevation model generation is possible without using photoclinometry.  I am not aware of a software package outside of planetary science that supports this technique.  I also would think that artificial light sources could skew the results in a city setting.